# Why there are two java path in my PC when i use the "mvn -v"

Tags: java, maven, cmd, mingw32

When I use `mvn spring-boot:run` to run a Spring Boot project, I find if use the command in `Cmd`, it works. but if I use it in `Git Bash`, it can't work.

So I use `java -version` and `mvn -v` to view the Java and maven version.

`java -version` give me the same result, but `mvn -v` result is different, as the picture shows:
[image: terminal output 1]

And when I see my java path, I'm sure it's `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`

[image: terminal output 2]

So I want to know, why there are two Java paths in my PC when I use `mvn -v`?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminals, instead just copy and paste the relevant terminal output as text into the question, formatted as "code" (monospace font). It's far more readable and easier to work with that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `java` executable and Maven by default use the JDK that is specified in the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

You are executing `java` and Maven (`mvn`) in different environments (`cmd.exe` in one case and Git Bash in the other case), so the most likely explanation is that `$JAVA_HOME` is set to different JDKs in the respective environments.

You can check the content of `$JAVA_HOME` with `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Hi，I found the real reason。There are three odious files `java.exe`, `javaw.exe`, and `javaws.exe` in the `C:\WINDOWS\System32` directory. 
No matter how you modify the environment variables, they will affect the version of java.Delete them, this problem is solved.